# Discord Bot how do you role someone from dms? Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here is my code

```
@client.command()
async def roledm(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
```

When you dm the bot with !roledm it gets your name but how would it go to my discord server and role them? how do I role people without using discord.utils.get( member.server.roles) , I just want to use my server ID to role them.

Comment: Users have no roles in a DM channel. You will have to use `get`.

Comment: hm, I just wanted it to go to my server and role them

Comment: Take a look at my answer, you still need to use `get` so that your bot knows what roles are in your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20utils%20get#discord.utils.get) to return the roles in your guild.

```
@client.command()
async def roledm(ctx):
    guild = client.get_guild(id=0000000000000000000000) # Guild ID
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=0000000000000000000000)  # Role ID
    member = guild.get_member(ctx.message.author.id)
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: Keep in mind you can use the name of the role `role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles,name="NAME HERE")`

Comment: doesnt work anymore can I get an updated version?

Comment: @Flaried, this answer does still work. are you placing the correct IDs into the get() functions?